# Media Queries for Tablet

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a situation where i have list of cards that has to be displayed in List view initially for a RWD Design. My requirement is to convert the list to a two column on a tablet which i am unable to. I have written media queries like

```
  `@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
     div {
            display: flex;
         }} `
```

I`enter code here`s this the right process for me to solve this situation.

Thanks

Comment: You are using any responsive library for example bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for work tablet size

```
  @media (max-width: 768px) { 
    type somthing
  }
```